# PySpark fill null values when respective column flag is zero

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a two dataframes as below

df1

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 021 | abc456 |
| def | 456 | xyz098 |

df2

| ref | column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I want to populate df1 column values to null where the df2 dataframe ref value A is zero

out_df_refA

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | Null | abc456 |
| def | Null | xyz098 |

Similarly for ref value B in df2 dataframe

out_df_refB

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Null | Null | abc456 |
| Null | Null | xyz098 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cross join to a filtered `df2` and use `when` to only keep the values in `df1` when the flag is not equal to 0.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

out_df_refA = (df1.alias('df1')
    .crossJoin(df2.filter("ref = 'A'").drop('ref').alias('df2'))
    .select(*[F.when(F.col('df2.' + c) != 0, F.col('df1.' + c)).alias(c) for c in df1.columns])
)

out_df_refA.show()
+-------+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|column3|
+-------+-------+-------+
|    abc|   null| abc456|
|    def|   null| xyz098|
+-------+-------+-------+
```

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

out_df_refB = (df1.alias('df1')
    .crossJoin(df2.filter("ref = 'B'").drop('ref').alias('df2'))
    .select(*[F.when(F.col('df2.' + c) != 0, F.col('df1.' + c)).alias(c) for c in df1.columns])
)
out_df_refB.show()
+-------+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|column3|
+-------+-------+-------+
|   null|   null| abc456|
|   null|   null| xyz098|
+-------+-------+-------+
```